# gRPC with Node.js, retry mechanism?

Tags: node.js, grpc

I am building a gRPC client in Node.js.
I want my failing calls to be executed a few more times before giving up.
I cannot find anything about this in the documentation, although there seems to be something similar but for the Go package.
Do you have any idea how to achieve this? If not possible with the grpc package, what is a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Node gRPC library currently does not have any built in retry mechanism. However, the recently added client interceptors API can be used to implement one. The [client interceptors designn document](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L5-NODEJS-CLIENT-INTERCEPTORS.md#advanced-examples) includes an example for implementing retries using that API.

Comment: updated link: https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L5-node-client-interceptors.md